# Cassandra partition with modulo-based timestamp

Tags: cassandra, partitioning, cql, cassandra-3.0

I will be capturing an event stream as records in a Cassandra table.  I might expect perhaps 1000 events every second, resulting in a 1000 rows per second.

In terms of partitioning, my presumption is to create a timestamp "bucket" for, perhaps, every 10 second interval.  My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE event ( 
   time_bucket timestamp,
   capture_time timeuuid,
   event_data text,
   PRIMARY KEY (time_bucket, capture_id)
);
```

ChatGPT suggested I could solve this problem using a modulo operation within an insert statement as follows:

```
INSERT INTO event_data (time_bucket, capture_time, event_data)
VALUES (
  toUnixTimestamp( now() ) - (toUnixTimestamp( now() ) % 10), 
  now(), 
  'Some data'
);
```

What seems strange to me is having the `now()` function called twice to create the "bucket" (and three times total, counting the `capture_time` column).  For perfect consistency, I'd like a way to call `now()` a single time, and use its value in all places.

So my questions are:

- Am I worrying about a non-issue?  Perhaps the ChatGPT example "works" and I should not attempt to improve it?
- Is there a way to re-write the insert CQL to call `now()` just a single time? For example, perhaps using some kind of CQL "variable"?
- Is this a reasonable approach to bucketize/partition my incoming event stream? Should I consider some alternative?

  - Sanity check: Is it reasonable to be using Cassandra for this purpose, in the first place?